# Angular ngResource array path variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngresource

I have trouble with angular's resource factory. I have path variable id and REST API accepts on same url also query parameter called "id". Let's describe this issue with some example:

Resource url: `"/person/:id"`

REST API also accepts query param id as filter: `"/person?id=5,7,11"` or `"/person?id=5&id=7&id=11"`

```
$resource("/person/:id", {id: [5, 7, 11]})
```

This produces invalid url `"/person/5,7,11"`. Did I miss something? I expected that array type cannot be assigned as path variable. Instead it should be converted automatically to query params(?id=5&id=7&id=11). Does anyone have idea how to override this behaviour? Btw. I cannot change name id. Thank you for suggestions..

Comment: remove the /:id and it should work I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$resource('/person/', {'id':[5, 7, 11]}
```

or, alternatively:

```
$resource("/person/?id=:myparams", {myparams: [5, 7, 11]})
```

Comment: I need combination with path variable id. Every object (person in this case) are represented by factory with one unique api path in form "/object/:id". So changing form of url or vars/params in one case out of 10 is not solution for me. I'm looking for generic way.. But thank you

Comment: Edit. Sorry. I did not see it first time. Your second tip is probably what I want..with little modification $resource("/person/:id?id=:myparams", {myparams: [5, 7, 11]})